# SQL azure data sync agent , no lo puedo instalar

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, azure, azure-sql

no puedo instalar el agente de sincronización de azure en windows server 2019, dice que me faltan privilegios para poder instalarlo, lo pruebo en mi computador windows 10 y me da el mismo problema, el problema es que soy administrador de los dos servidores y tengo todos los privilegios, aun así me sale el mismo error una y otra vez.

Tampoco permite darle click derecho y ejecutar como administrador.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! No se si este link al foro de [Microsoft](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a3a4565-0494-4dc7-841c-28ed8cf64b7a/cant-install-azure-sql-data-synchronize-agent-20?forum=ssdsgetstarted) puede ayudarte en algo

Comment: Hola xino_92, bienvenido. ¿has probado a ejecutar el instalador (.msi) con la opción "ejecutar como administrador"?

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje que te muestra indica que tu usuario no tiene privilegios para instalar **servicios**

Para dar privilegios debes ir al *Panel de Control --> Sistema y Seguridad --> Herramientas administrativas --> Directiva de Seguridad local*.

Aquí despliegas la carpeta *Directiva locales*, abres la carpeta *Asignación de derechos de usuarios*, buscas la directiva *Iniciar sesión como servicio* y en la lista agregas tu usuario.

Comment: Ya lo hice y no funciono, me arroja el mismo error al instalar.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución, y es un problema al momento de poner las credenciales de windows,
tiene que ir con este formato:
MACHINENAME \ UserName (por ejemplo, MyPC \ AdminUser) PC \ user.

con eso pude instalar el SQL data sync agent 2.0

Es difícil encontrar la solución ya que al momento de poner solo el user el instalador no arroja error de logon.